# Royalties with film

Tags: sound-design

Hello,

I'm doing some sound design work on a short film, i was wondering what your thoughts are on charging a flat fee for the project and how royalties might come into this if it made any money in the future. Am i entitled to royalties?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most shorts work on a flat flee... and probably a low one at that. If you are getting a flat fee make sure you haver an agreement drawn up entailing EXACTLY what said fee entails, and what will qualify as overages - otherwise you may end up doing far more for the fee than you thought.

As far as "royalties" go - non are "owed" to a sound designer (unlike a composer for example) but you can negotiate percentages however you and the producer want. Having said that, shorts don't make money... period. Even most features very seldom make money, at least on paper...